# Slight acos precision difference between Clang and Visual C++

Tags: c++, math

I have some cross platform code I'm working with. On the Mac it's compiled with Clang, on Windows it's compiled with Visual C++.

There is a calculation that can be sensitive, and there was a difference between Mac and Windows that was triggering asserts. It ends up there is a difference between acos results, but I'm not clear why.

On both platforms, the input to acos is exactly -1.0f. In Visual C++, `acos(-1.0f)` is 3.14159274. That's the value of pi as a float, which is what I'd expect.

But on macOS:

`float value = acos(-1.0f);`

...evaluates to 3.1415925. Thats just enough of an accuracy difference to trigger issues in the code. acos is an operation that can be imprecise with float - I understand that. And different compilers can have different implementations of acos. I'm just unclear why Clang seems to have issues with such a simple acos result while Visual C++ doesn't. A float is capable of representing 3.14159274, but that's not the result I'm getting.

It is possible to get an accurate/Visual C++ aligned value out of Xcode's version of Clang with:

`float value = (float)acos((double)-1.0f);`

So I can fix the issue by moving to higher accuracy, and then down casting the value back to float to preserve the same rounding as Windows. I'm just looking for a justification as to why the extra precision is necessary when the VC++ compiler doesn't seem to have a precision issue. It could be differences between the Clang/Xcode/VC++ math libraries as well. I just assumed that acos(-1.0) might be more settled across the compilers. I couldn't find any difference in round modes (even though rounding should not be necessary) and fresh projects in Xcode and Visual Studio show the same difference. Both machines are Intel.

Comment: Unrelated, but instead of `(double)-1.0f`, why not simply `-1.0`, which is guaranteed to be a `double`? If you ever feel the need to do a C-style cast in C++, then you should take that as a sign that you're probably doing something wrong.

Comment: I’d imagine the difference is actually between the processors rather than compilers, trigonometric functions have hardware instructions.

Comment: there are different ways to calculate `acos(1)` and how to implement it. There must not be a table that says `acos(1) == pi` but there can be one

Comment: There is generally no way to ensure bit-wise identical results for transcendental math functions across toolchains. If your code needs to run across multiple toolchains, you would want to adapt it to this reality. FWIW, `3.14159274` is greater than mathematical π (3.15159265...), and one *could* argue that `acos()` should never return a result that is mathematically "prohibited". Side remark: Are you sure you need `acos`? Some commonly encountered uses of `acos` can be replaced with algebraic computation.

Comment: @George - The Intel Mac I have runs both Windows and macOS. Both VC++ and Xcode on the same machine produce different outputs for acos. Could still be a difference in what instructions the two compilers use - but same CPU is being used across both.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude - You're right that the casting is unnecessary. This was taken from existing code, and I removed the variables and replaced them with constants. In context, there is a variable inside the acos that needs to be cast to double.

Comment: IEEE-754 doesn't require transcendental functions to be correctly rounded because that'll require far more memory and computational power [Floating point accuracy with different languages](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58411805/995714), [Why do sin(45) and cos(45) give different results?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31509332/995714), [Why do I get platform-specific result for std::exp?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54250126/995714), [Math precision requirements of C and C++ standard](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20945815/995714)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Math precision requirements of C and C++ standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20945815/math-precision-requirements-of-c-and-c-standard)

Comment: duplicates: [`asin` produces different answers on different platforms using Clang](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55245293/995714), [gcc and sin/cos/transcendental functions precision like in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15062728/995714)

Comment: `Could still be a difference in what instructions the two compilers use` no, there are only transcendental instructions in x87 and they're [extremely](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55665744/995714) [slow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12485190/995714) so no one uses them nowadays. C and C++ standard library implementations have their own faster software versions using the new SSE/AVX instruction sets

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look at the binary representation of these floating point values you can see that the mac/clang's value `A` is the next lowest floating-point number than windows/msvc's value `B`

```
A    3.14159250    0x40490FDA
B    3.14159274    0x40490FDB
```

Whilst B is closest to the true value of π, it is actually greater than π as @njuffa points out in their comment.

Reading the specification, it looks like `acosf` is supposed to return a value in the closed range [0,π].  Technically `A` meets this criteria whilst `B` doesn't.

In summary -

- `A` is the closest value to, but less than, π
- `B` is the closest value to π

The difference in these may be as a result of a deliberate decision of the respective standard library implementors.

I'd also observe that both values are true inverses of `cosf` as both `cosf(A)` and `cosf(B)` equal `-1.0f`.

Generally speaking, though, it is unwise to rely on exact bit-level accuracy with any floating point calculations. If you are not already aware of it, the document [What Every Computer Scientist Should
Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/800-7895/800-7895.pdf) explains why.

---

Edit: I was curious and found what might be relevant Apple source code [here](https://opensource.apple.com/source/Libm/Libm-315/Source/Intel/acosf.s.auto.html).

> ```
> Return value:
>     ...       
>     Otherwise:
>        ...            
>        Returns a value in [0, pi] (C 7.12.4.1 3).  Note that 
>        this prohibits returning a correctly rounded value for acosf(-1),
>        since pi rounded to a float lies outside that interval.
> ```

Comment: Thanks, this seems like the best answer - and the range requirement is possibly an explanation. This is existing code that was built using float, but this sounds like a justification to be either less picky about the float output, or move to double.